# SwiftUI Playground App issue accessing iCloud Files automatically

Tags: swift, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I’m trying to create a swiftui playground app for iOS and Mac Catalyst that will have a button to select a text file in iCloud and based upon the same file name and directory automatically load an additional file with a different format like an audio file.

This is a broken down snippet from my program.  Both the snippet and my program run fine on Mac with local files.  My program is setup a little different than the snippet and just to explain my program will select multiple types of formats and when I manually select a file locally or from iCloud it works.

This works locally.  Why not in iCloud?

Edit: last minute I noticed withSecurityScope doesn’t work on iOS but placing that to the side why would this work locally on a Mac but not with iCloud Drive on a Mac?

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
import AVKit
import MobileCoreServices


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fileContent: String = ""
    @State private var isShowingFilePicker: Bool = false
   @State private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            isShowingFilePicker = true
        }) {
            Text("Import")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $isShowingFilePicker, allowedContentTypes: [.plainText]) { result in
            if let selectedFileURL = try? result.get() {
                readText(from: selectedFileURL)
                loadAudio(from: selectedFileURL)
            } else {
                // Handle the error here
                print("Error selecting file")
            }
        }


        
        Text(fileContent)
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        
        if let audioPlayer = audioPlayer {
            AudioControlsView(audioPlayer: audioPlayer)
        }
    }
    .padding()
}

private func readText(from fileURL: URL) {
    do {
        fileContent = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print("Error reading file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

private func loadAudio(from fileURL: URL) {
    let audioFileName = fileURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent + ".mp3"
    let audioFileURL = fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent(audioFileName)
    
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: audioFileURL.path) {
        do {
            let bookmark = try audioFileURL.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
            
            var resolvedURL: URL?
            var isStale: Bool = false
            do {
                resolvedURL = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmark, options: .withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
            } catch {
                print("Failed to resolve bookmark for audio file: \(audioFileURL.path)")
            }
            
            if let resolvedURL = resolvedURL, let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: resolvedURL) {
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                self.audioPlayer = audioPlayer
            } else {
                print("Error initializing AVAudioPlayer")
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Error loading audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Audio file not found at path: \(audioFileURL.path)")
        audioPlayer = nil
    }
}    
}
 struct AudioControlsView: View {
let audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Button(action: {
            if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
                audioPlayer.pause()
            } else {
                audioPlayer.play()
            }
        }) {
            Image(systemName: audioPlayer.isPlaying ? "pause.circle.fill" : "play.circle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
}
struct ContentView_Previews:       PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```